# Unable to connect mysql database with android device

Tags: android, mysql, database, http

I am developing android application where the app is connected with mysql and php.

The database is perfectly connecting with emulator using `http://10.0.2.2/file.php` address.

But when I connect this app with my android device, it doesn't work.

For android device, I'm using my laptop ip-address http://192.168.0.XX/file.php.

I am using ubuntu OS in my laptop.

The activity loads first, I fill the form and when I click on submit button, the application stopped working and display a dialog that says :

**App is not working. Would you like to close it?**
Is there anything wrong in the below code,
Here it is my android code below :

**MainActivity.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener
{
    Button submit,button;
    EditText et1,et2,et3; 
    String url;
    CheckBox c1;
    InputStream is=null;
    String result=null;
    String line=null;
    int code;
    String Uname=null;
    String Email=null;
    String Mobile=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        submit.setOnClickListener(this);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(v==submit)
        {
            Uname=et1.getText().toString();
            Email=et2.getText().toString();
            Mobile=et3.getText().toString();
            if(Uname.isEmpty() || Uname.length()<0 ||
                    Email.isEmpty() || Email.length()<0 || 
                            Mobile.isEmpty() || Mobile.length()<0 )
            {
                Toast t=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please fill all the fields",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t.show();
            }
            else
            {
                insert();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Password has been sent to your mobile",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                et1.setText("");
                et2.setText("");
                et3.setText("");
                Intent i1=new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i1);
            }
        }
        else if(v==button)
        {
            Intent i1=new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }


    }

    public void insert() 
    {

        HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.XXX/file.php");

        try             
        {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair>pairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Uname", Uname));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email",Email));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Mobile",Mobile));

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost); 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is=entity.getContent();
            Log.e("Success","Connection Success");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Failed",ex.toString());          
        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader r1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            while((line=r1.readLine())!=null)
            {
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
            Log.e("Result", result);
            Log.e("Success Again", "Connection success-2");
        }
        catch(Exception ex1)
        {
            Log.e("Failed Again...","Unsuccess");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure ypur laptop and Android device are connected to the same network?

Comment: you are doing networking work over main thread, use asyncTask or thread for connection thing

Comment: @AshishKumar Yess..I am sure...

Comment: @Saqib But in emulator it's working...

Comment: then what error you getting? can u post your log error?

Comment: I am not getting any error...I forcefully have to close my app...

Comment: I am afraid then it's the issue I explained above, try that or post some more complete code of your whole class!

Comment: This is the main code that I've posted...other things are just Edittext and Button declarations...

Comment: @Saqib can you plzz tell me wht changes I have to make for async task..bcoz I never used it and no idea how to do it...plzz....

Comment: Are you able to reach http://192.168.0.XX/file.php in your mobile browser?

Comment: @Saqib tried async task too...but not working..!!!

Comment: are you able to access same url in your OS browser?

Comment: @Saqib you mean in my laptop running UBUNTU OS...!!! then YES...!!! but not in android device..:(

Comment: that's strange, all you can do is now debug code by printing and checking how far your code is going and let us know where it stuck

Comment: If you can reach the URL from your laptop browser but not from your mobile browser, then the devices are most probably connecting through different networks. Is your mobile connecting to the URL over mobile data or Wifi?

Comment: It would be helpful if you use ex.printStacktrace() in your catch block and share the Logcat error messages here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using wamp, you can edit httpd.conf file under wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\, replace "require local" with "require all granted"

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to check your laptop firewall or network restriction and if that is enabled then disable them.

Comment: how to you connect with your laptop directly wifi through? i mean your laptop wifi hotspot on and your device connect? or your laptop coneect to router and your device use router ip?

Comment: For internet, my laptop and my android device are connected with a wi-fi connection. My android device and laptop both together connected via USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

Check your ip in cmd as ipconfig
use this ip eg "http:\192.168.1.1\getlist.php"

and main thing turn off windows firewall